# combine checkbox alert function with detect function

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

the goal here is to detect if a user is checking out on my site and then prompt them with a special alert if they uncheck a box.

how do i combine to two functions to do this?

the detect function so far is this

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');

      if (pathArray.length >= 3) {
        if (pathArray[1].toLowerCase() == "commerce") {

          var page = pathArray[2].toLowerCase();
          if (page.indexOf("show-cart") == 0) {
            console.log("Detected the cart page."); // This works
          } else if (page.indexOf("checkout") == 0) {
            console.log("Detected the checkout page."); // Does not work (no injection)
          } else if (page.indexOf("order-confirmed") == 0) {
            console.log("Detected the order confirmation page."); // Does not work (no injection)
          }
        }
      }
```

and the checkbox alert function is this:

```
function validate() {
        var checkoutHistory = document.getElementById('shipToBilling');
        if (checkoutHistory.checked) {

        } else {
            alert("You have elected to turn off checkout history.");
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", validate, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `onclick` function can call both your functions

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: When the user clicks on the button, the onClick event can handle/call both his methods